# How should I protect against hard link attacks?

Tags: c, linux, security

- I want to append data to a file in /tmp.
- If the file doesn't exist I want to create it
- I don't care if someone else owns the file. The data is not secret.
- I do not want someone to be able to race-condition this into writing somewhere else, or to another file.

What is the best way to do this?

Here's my thought:

```
fd = open("/tmp/some-benchmark-data.txt", O_APPEND | O_CREAT | O_NOFOLLOW | O_WRONLY, 0644);
fstat(fd, &st);
if (st.st_nlink != 1) {
    HARD LINK ATTACK!
}
```

Problem with this: Someone can link the file to some short-lived file of mine, so that /tmp/some-benchmark-data.txt is the same as /tmp/tmpfileXXXXXX which another script of mine is using (and opened properly using O_EXCL and all that). My benchmark data is then appended to this /tmp/tmpfileXXXXXX file, *while it's still being used*.

If my other script happened to open its tempfile, then delete it, then use it; then the contents of that file would be corrupted by my benchmark data. This other script would then have to delete its file between the open() and the fstat() of the above code.

So in other words:

```
This script          Dr.Evil        My other script or program
                                    open(fn2, O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_RDWR)
                     link(fn1,fn2)
open(fn1, ...)
                                     unlink(fn2)
fstat(..)=>link is 1
write(...)
close(...)
                                    write(...)
                                    seek(0, ...)
                                    read(...) => (maybe) WRONG DATA!
```

And therefore the above solution does not work. There are quite possibly other attacks.

What's the right way? Besides not using a world-writable directory.

**Edit**:
In order to protect against the result that the evil user creates the file with his/her ownership and permissions, or just wrong permissions (by hard linking your file and then removing the original, or hardlinking a short-lived file of yours) I can check the ownership and permission bits after the nlink check.

There would be no security issue, but would also prevent surprises. Worst case is that I get some of my own data (from another file) at the beginning of the file copied from some other file of mine.

**Edit 2**:
I think it's almost impossible to protect against someone hard-linking the name to a file that's opened, deleted and then used. Examples of this is EXE packers, which sometimes even execute the deleted file via /proc/pid/fd-num. Racing with this would cause the execution of the packed program to fail. lsof could probably find if someone else has the inode opened, but it seems to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: It's only an attack before the file is created. If I am a standard user I can create a link to any file (even if I can't write to that file) in any directory I can write in. That means I can create a file called `/tmp/foo` thats a hard link of `/etc/passwd`. Now when his program writes to `/tmp/foo` it's really writing to `/etc/passwd`. He wants to avoid this by making sure that his was the first link to the inode he created.

Comment: @gabe: right. Which is why I'd check st_nlink. You can create a new link to other peoples files, but you can't remove them (decrease the link count).

Comment: Good point, Thomas. If my comment looks funny it's because I was replying to another comment that has since been deleted.

Comment: You can remove a link to a file if you have write permission on the directory holding the file, independently of the permissions on the file.  `ln /etc/passwd x; ls -l x; rm -f x`.

Comment: @Jonathan: No you can't. Not if the directory has the sticky bit. At least on Linux. What OS are you running?

Comment: @Thomas: hmmm, interesting.  MacOS X 10.6.3.  I did: `mkdir so; chmod 1777 so; cd so; ln /etc/passwd x; rm -f x; ls -la`.  However, I got away with it because I owned the directory.  I also did: `(mkdir so; su root -c 'chown other:other so; chmod 1777 so'; cd so; ln /etc/passwd x; rm -f x; ls -la; cd ..; rm -fr so;)` and this time I could not remove the file.  So, directory ownership is key.

Comment: @Thomas: Could you please explain what you intent to do? As far as I could guess, it seems like you want to allow others to read the contents of the temp file while preventing them from writing to the file. Why are you afraid of your file being hard-linked? Even if the file is hard linked, in the second run of your program, you will not open the same file, because the hard link must have a name different from "/tmp/some-benchmark-data.txt". You are opening the file by filename instead of by inode.

Comment: @Thomas: If what you are worrying is someone copying your data, or someone using an outdated copy of the benchmark, then you should prevent others from reading the file, because who can read the file can make a copy of it. Why don't you care who owns the file? In a properly setup /tmp (i.e. with the sticky bit turned on), only the owner of the file (or root) has permission to delete it. So, your worry of "hard-linking your file and then removing the original" doesn't make sense. If what you want is simply a temporary file, and you want to prevent naming collisions, tmpfile() is what you want.

Comment: @Thomas: The POSIX standard of tmpfile() could be found [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html).

Comment: @Siu Ching Pong: No, I want to write a file to /tmp without being fooled into overwriting anything. I want to use the same name for the file, so yes, the next time I run the program the file will already be there. So tmpfile() is not what I want. Nor is O_EXCL.

Comment: @Thomas: Let me re-phrase your question. Please see whether this is correct and accurate: **`(1)`** You want to append data to the file `"/tmp/some-benchmark-data.txt"`. **`(2)`** If the file doesn't exist, you will create it. **`(3)`** You **DON'T** care if someone else is able to read the data. **`(4)`** You **DO** worry if someone else has already created the file with some contents in it, **or owns the file**, or can write to the file (by the means of writing to the file directly or to a hard link of it), or can delete the file `"/tmp/some-benchmark-data.txt"`.

Comment: @Siu Ching Pong: No, point 4 should be that I worry about someone being able to trick me (race condition) into overwriting something, or writing something to a file in use somewhere else.

Comment: @Thomas: I wonder your definition of "race condition" is the same as what it generally means. A "race condition" is usually used to describe a situation in multi-threading. Please see [the Computing section here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) for more information. I can't see any "race condition" in your case if the file is owned by you and has the permission 0644, because others (I mean programs run by another user) cannot write to it, cannot delete it, can create a hard-link on it but cannot change the file in any way via the hard-link.

Comment: @Thomas: I still don't realize what the "hard-link" problem is. Can you demonstrate the problem by commands? Here're the commands I used: **`(1)`** `sudo -u www-data touch /tmp/test-123` (Create a file using the privilege of the user `www-data`) **`(2)`** `ln /tmp/test-123` (Create a hard-link of the file in the current dir.) **`(3)`** `chown kenji test-123` (Permission denied) **`(4)`** `echo A > test-123` (Permission denied). This shows that even people can hard-link to your file, they can't do anything with it. `3` and `4` should return an error, otherwise there's a problem in your system.

Comment: @Siu Ching Pong: It's the same as everybody elses definition (maybe not yours then, if you don't understand me). In this case it would be some evil person linking or unlinking a file between open() and fstat(). Or other evilness. That would be "dependent on the sequence or timing of other events". First sentence from wikipedia. The comment fields are horrible for this kind of demonstration, so no. With your 4-step thing above you are missing the issue at hand. I will check to see if I can improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, you'll generally get a race condition where someone else creates a link, then removes it by the time your fstat() system call executes.

You've not said exactly what you're trying to prevent. There are certainly kernel patches which prevent making (hard or symbolic) links to files you don't own in world-writable directories (or sticky directories).

Putting it in a non world-writable directory seems to be the right thing to do.

SELinux, which seems to be the standard enhanced security linux, may be able to configure policy to forbid users to do bad things which break your app.

In general, if you're running as root, don't create files in /tmp. Another possibility is to use setfsuid() to set your filesystem uid to someone else, then if the file isn't writable by that user, the operation will simply fail.

Comment: I thought of this, but if they create a link to a file they don't own then they won't be able to delete that link. In a o+t directory that /tmp is you can only delete files (links) that you own. So they won't be able to decrease st_nlink back to 1.

Comment: Yes but they might be able to delete it from the other directory it's in, if they have write access.

Comment: But what do they win then? Isn't that the same as they creating the file in /tmp the first place to be appended to?

Answer (score 1):

Short of what you just illustrated, the only other thing I've tried ended up almost equally racey and more expensive, establishing inotify watches on /tmp *prior* to creating the file, which allows for catching the event of a hardlink in some instances.

However, its still  really racey and inefficient, as you would also need to complete a breadth first search of /tmp, at least up to the level that you want to create the file.

There (to my knowledge) is no "sure" way to avoid this kind of race, other than not using word writeable directories. What are the consequences of someone intercepting your i/o via hard link .. would they get anything useful  or just make your application exhibit undefined behavior?

Comment: The data itself is not secret. It's just benchmarking data. "Function X took 2 seconds".